# mod rewrite hide directory structure

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I moved all the files/folders in the root to a folder `v1.0` and used the following:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^v1.0/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) v1.0/$1 [L]
```

This works and the site now accesses files inside `v1.0`. The problem is when directly accessing the folders.

This: `http://example.com/includes` (includes exists)

forwards the url to

`http://example.com/v1.0/includes` and shows this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /v1.0/includes/ on this server.
```

How can the folder structure not be exposed, both in the URL and in the error message?

Comment: Is `/v1.0/includes/` a real directory? Can you show your full .htaccess by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged .htaccess, I assume that you have your rule in your .htaccess. In this context, the first argument of `RewriteRule` will match against an url that will guaranteed NOT begin with a slash, as that is part of the common prefix.

I think the easiest solution is to add custom error pages for forbidden and not found errors. See the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive for more information.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /v1.0/errordocuments/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /v1.0/errordocuments/404.php
```

Then make those pages with the relevant information you want to show.

Comment: Yes, I have done that with 404, and will probably will do with 403 too. But the folder structure is still exposed in the URL.

Comment: Your rule does an internal rewrite, not a redirect. If the url is visible in the address bar (instead of just the error body), a redirect is taking place. Where does this redirect originate from?

Comment: When I enter `http://example.com/includes` in the browser URL bar it's directed to `http://example.com/v1.0/includes`. I don't want anyone to see `v1.0`.